# PHP MySQL Dump Script Help

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a script to create a dump of a mysql database, however, I can't get it working. Below is the code I'm suing.

```
    $file = 'backup_'.substr(md5(TIME_NOW), 0, 10).random_str(30);
    header('Content-Type: text/x-sql');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'.sql"');            

    // process backup
    $time = date('dS F Y \a\t H:i', TIME_NOW);
    $header = "-- Database Backup\n-- Generated: {$time}\n-- -------------------------------------\n\n";
    $contents = $header;

    $table_selects = array();
    $table_list = $db->list_tables($config['database']['database']);
    foreach($table_list as $id => $table_name)
    {
        $table_selects[$table_name] = $table_name;
    }

    $field_list = array();
    $fields_array = $db->show_fields_from($table_name);
    foreach($fields_array as $field)
    {
        $field_list[] = $field['Field'];
    }       

    $query = $db->simple_select($table);
    while($row = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO {$table} ($fields) VALUES (";
        $comma = '';
        foreach($field_list as $field)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$field]) || is_null($row[$field]))
            {
                $insert .= $comma."NULL";
            }
            else
            {
                $insert .= $comma."'".$db->escape_string($row[$field])."'";
            }
            $comma = ',';
        }
        $insert .= ");\n";
        $contents .= $insert;
        clear_overflow($fp, $contents);
    }
```

But it's not working...and I know I have some of the code wrong, such as what tables to select (I want to select all the tables).

Comment: Why don't you dump it in the terminal?

Comment: Because I'm creating a custom "server control panel", and I need an easy way to back up a predefined database.

Answer (score 2):

Below might be an easier way to backup your database without having to process all the information.  Since it is a MySQL statement, it will probably also run blazingly fast.

From here:
http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

```
<?php  
    include 'config.php';  
    include 'opendb.php';  

    $tableName  = 'mypet';  
    $backupFile = 'backup/mypet.sql';  
    $query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";  
    $result = mysql_query($query);  

    include 'closedb.php';  
?>
```